# Authentication on external sites with Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there a drupal module that would allow external sites to authenticate with drupal credentials? I mean something like "Login with Facebook" button, but with Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with [OpenID Provider](https://drupal.org/project/openid_provider) drupal module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Connector](https://drupal.org/project/connector) and [oAuthConnector](https://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector) modules.

Comment: There was a 'Drupal' module used to ship with Drupal 5.x which offered exactly the same feature. But it was removed from 6.x. Try other modules having similar features!